# Background disappears with scroll bar. Why?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have: 800px `width` div's inside a 100% `width` container with a background image repeating horizontally.

Live: http://www.baskra.com

When I resize the browser window, a scroll bar is generated. When I scroll it, I see that the background image is only applied to the original unscrolled region, as seen above.

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcdXK (Not every image is working, but I believe the most important here is the CSS.)

Comment: Looks like it's an overflow issue. Try applying `overflow:auto` to `.pages-container`

Comment: Jack, it solves the problem, but then it makes the scroll bar disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the "width: 100%" from .pages-container CSS class with a "min-width: 800px" – it will force background to be the same width as the container if the window size becomes less than 800px.

```
.pages-container {
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-image: url('http://baskra.com/images/bg/bg-scroll.png');
   background-repeat: repeat;
   min-width: 800px;
   left: 0;
}
```

Check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/wcdXK/3/

Comment: Now I understand the logic. I applied the same rule to my slideshow and it's working perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Because the width applies to the area of the containing block, as the overall container is smaller the background shrinks to apply to the same area (along with the pages-container element).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are experiencing many problems on your layout (you posted a similar question)

You should read a Responsive Web Design article trying to understand media queries

like this (random picked from google) http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/

Comment: I actually suggested the use of media queries, but the client couldn't afford it at this moment. It happens! The website is completed, I just need to solve this scroll bar issue.